# No functions in phash.dll

Tags: dll, autoit, phash

Want to call DLL of open source perceptual hash library pHash inside an AutoIt script.

But in phash.dll, as DLL Export Viewer says, only 6 functions:
closedir, opendir, readdir, rewinddir, seekdir and telldir.

I am missing something important

Comment: What is the problem? You've got 6 functions: closedir, opendir, readdir, rewinddir, seekdir and telldir. How many should be there?

Comment: Looking at the header file you may have to install some of the dependencies and then recompile with the `HAVE_IMAGE_HASH` and `HAVE_VIDEO_HASH`. It's unusual on windows to expect the user to compile the binary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd send an email to the developers as it looks like they've compiled dirent from the exports and called it pHash. Definitely something not right there. I get the same result as you from the dll in the Release and Debug folders from the download page.

I just compiled it myself, using the following commands:

```
g++ -c *.cpp
g++ -shared pHash.o -o pHash.dll
```

And I get the following exported functions:

```
_Z19ph_hamming_distanceyy
ph_about
ph_bitcount8
ph_compare_text_hashes
ph_hammingdistance2
ph_readfilenames
ph_texthash
phash_version
```

I can then call the `ph_about` function from AutoIt:

```
MsgBox(0, "ph_about", ph_about())

Func ph_about()
    Local $aResult = DllCall("pHash.dll", "str", "ph_about")
    If @error Then Return SetError(@error, @extended, "")

    Return $aResult[0]
EndFunc   ;==>ph_about
```

If you just need text hashing and don't have the toolchain installed then pop me an email and I'll send you the binary I compiled. I don't have any permanent hosting so I won't add the link here where it will rot in a few months time.

As mentioned in my comment, if you want to hash image or video files then you have to install the dependencies listed on [this page](http://www.phash.org/download/) and compile with the `HAVE_IMAGE_HASH` and `HAVE_VIDEO_HASH` flags set.